# Subir la pagina arriba al enviar AJAX

Tags: jquery

Buenas tengo un formulario el que al rellenarlo lo envio por AJAX, al dar el botón si quita todo el formulario y sale la respuesta con los resultados. Pero al visualizarlo en dispositivo movil, como se quita el formulario se me queda la página abajo, entonces si no suben no pueden ver los resultados.

El jquery

```
$(function(){
    $("#mensaje").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var f = $(this);
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("mensaje"));
        formData.append("dato", "valor");

        $.ajax({
            url: "respMensaje.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,

             beforeSend: function(){
              $("#mensaje").html("<div class='ui active inline loader myLoader'></div>")
              },
             success: function (resultado){
              setTimeout(function(){
                $("#mensaje").html(resultado);
              }, 1300);
            }
          });
            /*  setTimeout(function () {
                location.reload();
              }, 5000); *///will call the function after 2 secs
       });
       });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo que quieres hacer es que al enviarse el formulario, la página haga un scroll automatico al principio para que los usuarios puedan ver los resultados.

En ese caso, el código que necesitas es este:

```
$('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
```

Si quieres hacer scroll dentro de un elemento concreto puedes utilizar el selector adecuado igualmente.

Para que todo el efecto funcione bien, debes ponerlo dentro del success de tu código, así:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#mensaje").html(resultado);
    //lo ponemos después de que se muestre la respuesta.
    $('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
}, 1300);
```

Comment: Donde lo situo en el beforeSend?? gracias @cooper

Comment: Lo probe tanto en el `beforeSend` como en el `success` y no funciona @cooper

Comment: @Miguel prueba en el success como te pongo.

Comment: no me funciona @cooper

Comment: Perdona @cooper en el movil si funciona, lo estaba comprobando desde el firebug de google